# Cutting a string using multiple delimiters using the awk or sed commands

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut

I am using a SIPP server simulator to verify incoming calls. 
What I need to verify is the caller ID and the dialed digits. I've logged this information to a file, which now contains, for example, the following:

```
From: <sip:972526134661@server>;tag=60=.To: <sip:972526134662@server>}
```

in each line.

What I want is to modify it to a csv file containing simply the two phone numbers, such as follows:

```
972526134661,972526134662
```

and etc.

I've tried using the `awk -F` command, but then I can only use the `sip:` as a delimiter or the `@` or `/` as delimiters.

While, basically what I want to do is to take all the strings which begin with a `<` and end with `>`,  and then take all the strings that follow the `sip:` delimiter.

using the `cut` command is also not an option, as I understand that it cannot use strings as delimiters.

I guess it should be really simple but I haven't find quite the right thing to use.. Would appreciate the help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, for fun, picking some random data (from your original post) and using `awk -F` as you originally wanted.

To note, because your file is "generated", we can assume a regular format for the data and not expect the "short" patterns to cause mis-hits.

```
[g]awk -F'sip:|@' -v OFS="," '{print $2,$4}' yourlogfile
```

It uses both `sip:` and `@` as the Field Separator, by means of the *alternation operator* `|`. It can easily be extended to allow further characters or strings to also be used to separate fields in the input if required. The built-in variable FS can contain a regular expression/regexp like this.

For that first sample in your question, it yields this:

```
972526134661,972526134662
```

For the latest (revision 8) version, and guessing what you want:

```
[g]awk -F'sip:|@|to_number:' -v OFS="," '{print $2,$5}' yourlogfile
```

Yields this:

```
from_number,972526134662
```

The [g]awk is because I used gawk on my machine, and got same behaviour with awk.

Slight amendment in style, suggested by @fedorqui, to use the command-line option -v to set the value for the Output Field Separator (an AWK built-in variable which can be amended using -v like any other variable) and separating the print fields with a comma, so that they are treated in the output as fields, rather than building a string with a hard-coded "," and treating it as one field.

Comment: Nice! Note you can also set the output field separator with `-v OFS=","`  so that you don't have to hardcode it in your `print` statement.

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks. Updated. I rarely do "command line" awks, much preferring to `-f` them, so I'd usually have that stuff in the BEGIN.

Comment: There is no difference. `awk -v OFS="," '...'` is entirely equivalent to `awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","}'`, no matter how you invoke the code.

Comment: @fedorqui yes, it's just that the `-v` is only a feeble awareness in the back of my mind. I personally (almost) always write the awk in a file. I find it easier to re-use/find again. Since this was for a "command line", better to have the -v and the fields, rather than what I had originally.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using sed to extract the two numbers:

```
$ sed -n 's/^From: <sip:\([0-9]*\).*To: <sip:\([0-9]*\).*/\1,\2/p' file
972526134661,972526134662
```

The regular expression matches a line beginning with `From` and captures the two numbers after `<sip:`. If the spaces are variable, you may want to add `*` to those places.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex replace, as long as the format stays the same (order is always From/To):

```
sed -E "s/^.*sip:([0-9]+)@.*sip:([0-9]+)@.*$/\1,\2/"
```

It's not a very specific or perfect solution, but in most cases an approach like this is enough.

Comment: Clearly you haven't tested your solution - it is missing the `/` at the end of the `s` command and uses extended regular expressions, so needs the `-r` (or `-E`) switch in order to work.

Comment: I appologize for submitting a bit prematurely, I'm on my phone and trying it out right now

Comment: Thanks, this works great, as long as the format doesn't change, and since it is set ahead it is not supposed to.

Comment: you can also add the *from* and *to* parts to the pattern, that way it will "break" when the pattern changes